# Get the Parent List in a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, datacontext

my Problem is the following:
i have a treeView, which is bounded to the ItemsSource. The SelectedItem is bound
to a property in my ViewModel called SelectedItem.

The ItemsSource is build like:

```
public class Item
{
      public Header { get; set; }
      public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemChildren { get; set; }
.
.
.
}
```

I want to Delete, Reorder... the Items. So I Need the parent List of the SelectedItem to do this. I could Research all Lists for the item, but the item can exists twice and for Separators the item can be null.

Does anyone knows how I can get the parent list of the selected Item?

Thank u very much!

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the tree, then you don't need the List of parents but only a reference to a parent:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item() 
    {
        _col = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        _col.CollectionChanged +=
            new NotifyCollectionChanged(ItemChildren_CollectionChanged);
    }

    public Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemChildren
    { get { return _col; } }

    public Item Parent { get { return _parent; } }

    private void ItemChildren_CollectionChanged(
        object sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // for all newly added items: item._parent = this;
        // for all removed items: item._parent = null;
    }

    private Item _parent;
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _col;

}
```

This solution is more complex than what you started with. Parent object must track its children and make sure that child object's Parent is set to it every time when child is added to it.

I have been typing this code without syntax checking, but it hits the point. You can find the whole source code for almost the same question in this article: [How to Implement Collection Property to Contain Unique Objects](http://www.sysexpand.com/?path=howto/collection-property).

EDIT: Note that `Item` class in code above does not allow callers to set `ItemChildren` collection. That collection is created and served by the Item instance and nobody is allowed to change it. But anybody is allowed to add/remove items in it. One more thing is the way in which Item handles newly added child items - you are free to throw `InvalidOperationException` if someone attempts to add an item with non-null Parent reference! That would ensure that your structure remains the tree. For example, `XmlNode` class (`System.Xml`) throws `InvalidOperationException` from `AppendChild` method if argument is already an ancestor of current node. Possibilities are endless when `Item` has opportunity to verify elements that are added to it.